# Can I speed up the asynchronous load of this page?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm loading a search result into a table with the JQuery below:

```
$("#searchForm").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(),
    function (data) {
        if ($("#addResult").is(':checked')) {
            $("#myTable tbody").append(data);
        } else {
            $("#myTable tbody").html(data);
        }
        $("#myTable").trigger("update");
    });
});
```

The data I return is a varying number of rows: `<tr></tr>...<tr></tr>`.

Firefox is of course much faster than IE. If I load < 1k rows it's pretty fast in both browsers. But when I return ~9k rows IE hangs for about 5sec before presenting the data. It's also very slow to scroll all rows in IE. I don't use paging but I want to know if there's a way around this before I start paging the result?

I also get an error in IE when I click any link, to move away from the search page, about a slow running script. But why do I get this when I move away from the page? I don't have any scripts that should run at that point? Or do IE do something behind the scenes when browsing away from a large search result?

Comment: Are you really showing 9k rows on one page? Maybe server-side pagination would help?

Comment: 9k rows means its time to get down to paging...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insertion of that many items is going to be tough for browsers to handle.  Perhaps you should change your approach.  Maybe you could paginate it a number of items that provides usability and performance.  Say 1000?  Then you only ever insert 1000 at a time.

The DOM is a slow creature.  It's best not poke it with such a large stick if you can avoid it.

Comment: 9k rows is not a large stick its a `.22 caliber` :)

Comment: Yeah, I just wanted to be sure there weren't any way around it. Pagination it is then...

Comment: Definitely good advice to avoid manipulating the DOM like that. I'd get the OP to have a read of this. http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/efficient-javascript/?page=3

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are receiving html data. If you could have the server return a JSON object instead of html you could save on bandwidth. JSON is much leaner than xml or html. See also http://www.json.org/xml.html.

The tables can then be created using Javascript on client (browser).

Answer (score 0):

jquery .append() and .html() are **extremely** slow, overall in tables.

you can use pure javascript object.innerHTML = ... instead, or at least try it to comapre.

```
$("#searchForm").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(),
    function (data) {
        var elm = $("#myTable tbody").get(0);
        if ($("#addResult").is(':checked')) {
            elm.innerHTML += data;
        } else {
            elm.innerHTML = data;           
        }
        $("#myTable").trigger("update");
    });
});
```

here is what I use in production:

```
url = "yata.php";
    $('#waitMessage').show();
    console.log('start');
    console.time('load');
    $.get(url, function(data) {
        console.timeEnd('load');
        // 11 seconds to load all rows (14.8 megs)

        console.time('append');
        $('tbody').append(data);
        console.timeEnd('append');
        // 7 seconds

        /*
        console.time('appendChild');
        bod = $('tbody').get(0);
        bod.innerHTML += data;
        console.timeEnd('appendChild');
        */
        // 9 secondes

        $('#waitMessage').hide();

    });
```

herrr, well, seems things have changed ^^'

Comment: I get an error on `elm.innerHTML = data`. I also googled it and it says innerHTML is difficult to use with `tr` and tables in generall. Have you gotten this to work yourself?

Comment: I could get it work, i have updated my response with what I use in production. Could you please tell me your error. I remember I got issues with several "tbody" created in some bad old browser.

Comment: I added the console.time and I got these times: `load:1868ms`(3.8megs) and `append:1557ms`. I load 9k rows. This is measured in Firefox since IE can't handle console.time

Comment: It just says `unknown runtime error` in IE8 on this line: `elm.innerHTML = data;`. I don't know what more to give you =/

Comment: arf it's some ie8 limitation: [linkage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/555965/javascript-replace-innerhtml-throwing-unknown-runtime-error) and [linkage](http://www.theogray.com/blog/2009/06/internet-explorer-unknown-runtime-error). Anyway, as said, pagination seems indeed the way to go. You won't be able to display these 9k rows much faster.