# GWT set inner HTML giving Unknown runtime error

Tags: gwt, innerhtml

Please let me know what i am doing wrong here:

I need to add dynamic content to my htmy table using GWT.
I am using setInnerHTML method for this

```
Element tableElement=(Element) Document.get().getElementById("htmltable");
tableElement.setInnerHTML("<tr><td>1</td><td>2000</td><td>2</td><td>3000</td></tr>");
```

But i am getting this error
    com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (Error): Unknown runtime error
    number: -2146827688
    description: Unknown runtime error

Please let me know what i am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

this can be due to multiple reasons.

If this is happening on IE only this post covers it: [Debugging IE8 Javascript Replace innerHTML Runtime Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555965/javascript-replace-innerhtml-throwing-unknown-runtime-error)

In Ie you can not set the inner html of a table element.

From GWT CellTableImplementation for IE:

> IE doesn't support innerHTML on tbody, nor does it support removing or
>   replacing a tbody. The only solution is to remove and replace the rows
>   themselves.